# Enhanced Ecommere GTM - GA in Magento 1.9.x

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Could you recommend me how to develop an enhanced **e-commerce** for **Magento 1.9.x**?

I think having an enhanced **e-commerce** with **Google analytics** is very good.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably several Extensions out there, which provide this functionality. As you are probably a developer, you can also look up the documentation which values are needed on which page type, apply it normally in Magento.

some more information how to add something can be found here https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce

You should at least know, how to add own templates, to generate the required Javascript for this.